# VSCode not suggesting or autocompleting any imports

Tags: visual-studio-code

VSCode has stopped autocompleting and Intellisense has become unusable for me.

For components that are in my src or already imported, it works initially but then will stop after sometime, sometimes eventually autocompleting after ~5-10s.

It completely has stopped importing anything from node_modules. However, if I type something and press `ctrl`+`space` (`editor.action.triggerSuggest`), it will load the suggestions that I was seeing before as I typed.

Is there a way to fix this?